# Android start/stop repeating Thread after specific time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I need a thread repeating after 30 seconds that load data from web service.
i want to stop and start thread onResume and onPause so that it runs when screen is active and disable it when activity paused. Restart on resume.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            dataIfInternet(refreshTop);
        }

    }, 30000);
```

How to stop it when activity paused.

Comment: *How to stop it when activity paused.* seriously? 1. naive way: do some check before `dataIfInternet` call 2. or... check in Handler's docs if there is some method to remove callback

Comment: Use GCMNetworkManager.

Comment: Any refrence or sample of GCMNetworkManager?

Comment: Check my answer below
it will solve your problem and give me feedback.

Answer (score 0):

U can't **pause** the handler, so u need to cancel it in your `onPause` and post in again in your `onResume`

so u probably want something like this:

```
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
```

in your `onResume()`

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        dataIfInternet(refreshTop);
    }
};
myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 30000);
```

and in your `onPause()`

```
// Cancel the runnable
myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

I hope this solves your problem